# Set every element to zero in matrix unless it's 1 or 1/2

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I have the following code:

```
max = 1;

PotentialTilde[V0_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> V0/1, Band[{2, 1}] -> V0/2, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> V0/2}, {2*max + 1, 2*max + 1 }];

a = KroneckerProduct[PotentialTilde[1], PotentialTilde[1]] // 
  MatrixForm
```

That generates this matrix:

[[image: <span class=]$$ $$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QyqL.png)

---

How do I set every element that is **not** equal to `1` or `1/2` to `0`?

Comment: Something like `a /. {1 -> 0, 1/2 -> 0}` should do it.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the opposite. Anything that is NOT equal to 1 and 1/2

Comment: Also, your command does not change anything to my `a`

Comment: Look up [`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html). Also, if you want to change `a`, you have to assign the result to `a` again. (In Mathematica, barely anything changes variables, most things are immutable)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread (and I wasn't at a computer). Glad you've found the answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be careful with assigning a "form" (e.g. `MatrixForm`) to a variable. Another observation is that `a` is a [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) uses rules to store the values and since `ReplaceAll` works with the `FullForm` of an expression care has to be taken (using [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) will make the array a regular matrix again).

This should work:

```
max = 1;
PotentialTilde[V0_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> V0/1, Band[{2, 1}] -> V0/2, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> V0/2}, {2*max + 1, 2*max + 1}];

a = KroneckerProduct[PotentialTilde[1], PotentialTilde[1]];
(* a // MatrixForm *)

aMod = (a // Normal) /. x_?NumericQ /; Not@MatchQ[x, 1 | 1/2] -> 0;
aMod // MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix]

Lukas Lang's suggestion is even nicer:

```
aMod = (a // Normal) /. Except[1 | 1/2, _?NumericQ] -> 0;
```

**UPDATE**

@HenrikSchumacher is of course right in warning against the use of `Normal` for a `SparseArray` -- after all there may have been a good reason for using it in the first place. So for a pattern replacement solution the use of [`ArrayRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules.html) may be safer:

```
aMod = ( a // ArrayRules ) // RightComposition[
    ReplaceAll @ Rule[ 
        Rule[{row_?NumericQ, col_?NumericQ}, Except[ 1 | 1/2, _?NumericQ ],
        Rule[{row,col}, 0]
    ]
    , SparseArray
];
aMod // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Huh, never apply `Normal` to `SparseArray`s. Hell might break loose... ;) (Anyways, +1 of course.)

Answer (score 11):

```
A = KroneckerProduct[PotentialTilde[1], PotentialTilde[1]];
B = A (1 - Unitize[A - 1/2] Unitize[A - 1]);
B // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It is even *much* more efficient to use machine precision numbers:

```
max = 100;
A = KroneckerProduct[PotentialTilde[1], PotentialTilde[1]];
B = A (1 - Unitize[A - 1/2] Unitize[A - 1]); // RepeatedTiming // First

NA = N[A];
NB1 = NA (1. - Unitize[NA - 0.5] Unitize[NA - 1.]); // RepeatedTiming // First

Max[Abs[B - NB]]
```

> 0.269
>
> 0.0163
>
> 0.

It is even faster (but also quite a bit more tedious, though), to operate only on the list of nonzero values by using the low-level representation of `SparseArray` and the following *undocumented* constructor:

```
NB2 = SparseArray[
     SparseArray @@ {
       Automatic,
       Dimensions[NA],
       NA["Background"],
       {1(*version of SparseArray implementation*),
        {
         NA["RowPointers"],
         NA["ColumnIndices"]
         },
        With[{vals = NA["NonzeroValues"]},
         vals Subtract[1., Unitize[vals - 0.5] Unitize[vals - 1.]]
         ]
        }
       }
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00670

The advantage over modifying `ArrayRules` is that it leaves all arrays packed (they can only be packed for machine precisision numbers or machine integers; not for symbolic entries), while `ArrayRules` unpacks the list of nonzero positions and nonzero values in order to generate the symbolic list of rules.

Should you wonder why `SparseArray` appears twice here:  `SparseArray@@{...}` constructs the sparse array literally by the row pointers, column indices and "nonzero values" provided, even if there are actually zeroes among the "nonzero values"; wrapping this with a further `SparseArray` removes these "ghosts" from the internal representation, so that `NB2["NonzeroValues"]` returns really only the nonzero values.

Comment: (+1) Very concise and elegant. I updated my solution - maybe for a pattern matching solution applying `ArrayRules` instead of `Normal` is saver?

Comment: @gwr Jepp, it definitely is.

Answer (score 7):

a cannot be a MatrixForm:

```
(a = KroneckerProduct[PotentialTilde[1], 
    PotentialTilde[1]]) // MatrixForm
```

Convert to a regular Matrix:

```
Normal[a] /. {ij_ /; (NumberQ[
       ij] && ( ij != 1/2 && ij != 1)) :> 0}

(a = Normal[
     a] /. {ij_ /; (NumberQ[
          ij] && ( ij != 1/2 && ij != 1)) :> 
      0}) // MatrixForm
a

MatrixForm[a]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a UnitStep[a - 1/2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$